# syntax of yaml file - what is the meaning of "<<:"?

Tags: yaml

I am working with hyperledger examples and cannot find reference to YAML syntax I see in the configtx.yaml file.  Specifically, what is with "<<:" ?  For example:

```
Profiles:
    TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis:
        Capabilities:
            <<: *ChannelCapabilities
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
```

Is this some sort of line continuation syntax?  Does that mean 'go back to the colon on the previous line' ?

I can find no documentation on "<<:"  As a matter of fact, if I put that string in a search, very weird messages appear in multiple languages - but that's another story ...

Comment: This is called a YAML Extension.  It's used to build on top of another object that's being anchored in.  [Here is a quick guide](https://blog.daemonl.com/2016/02/yaml.html)

Answer (score 2):

The official name for this is [Merge Key](https://yaml.org/type/merge.html). You will likely find more information searching for this name.

Merge keys are one of the (optional) types defined as a draft for YAML 1.1: [Language-Independent Types](https://yaml.org/type/).
Although they were just a draft, many processors implemented them.

In some YAML processors, they are optional, some implement them by default.

Merge keys are usually used for defining defaults:

```
---
defaults: &defaults
  A: default for A
  B: default for B

some-mapping:
  << : *defaults
  A: foo
  C: bar

--- # will result in the same as:
some-mapping:
  A: foo
  B: default for B
  C: bar
```

Some background:

Note that YAML 1.2 has a bit different kind of type resolving (see [my blog article](http://blogs.perl.org/users/tinita/2018/01/introduction-to-yaml-schemas-and-tags.html) for an explanation and comparison).
Some of the new definitions in the [YAML 1.2 Schema definitions](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#Schema) are different and not backwards compatible to 1.1. (Although the YAML 1.2 Spec actually mentions it, but doesn't say anything about the incompatibility.)

Merge Keys are definitely quite handy sometimes, but are difficult to implement in a generic way, like almost all of the other standard types.

Also there is currently no standard way to merge sequences like that. This only works for mappings.